# Why the plot of $\sqrt{x}$ has no negative part??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

We all know that for every real and positive number $N$ we have

$$\sqrt{N} = \pm a$$

for example $\sqrt{25} = \pm 5$.

Now: why the plot of the function $\sqrt{x}$ has only a positive part in the Cartesian plane? I have two results, plus and minus a certain number, so why the plot takes into account only the positive results?

Comment: No, $\sqrt{25}$ is not $\pm 5$; it's $5$, by definition.

Comment: You could plot $f(x)=-\sqrt x$ to get the negative branch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition $\sqrt{x}$ indicates the positive (or [principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses)) square root of $x$. If we want indicate all the two root we have to write explicitly $\pm\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Oh thank you!! That was a doubt I had since lots of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ usually refers to the principal square root which is defined as the nonnegative solution to $r^2=x$ for $x\ge0$.

While it's true that in general there are two solutions to the equation $r^2=x$, we really like single valued functions.

Comment: Of course, a multi-valued function would be an oxymoron (i.e. not really a function).

Comment: @JohnJoy Not true, this would still be a function, but on a different target set.

Comment: @Did Of course, you are correct, if the elements of range of the function are themselves, sets (e.g. $\{-1,1\}\in S$).

Answer (score 3):

The √ symbol is used to denote the principal square root of a number, i.e. the positive one.